# is there a better way to do this

Tags: vb.net, browser, loops, webforms, setattribute

so i have a loop in vb.net that loads a webpage, fills out a form and clicks submit

I currently am using these for, respectively, waiting for the webpage to load, filling out the form, and clicking submit

```
   Do While Not browser.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete

            System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
        Loop
```

and

```
        browser.Document.GetElementById("text").SetAttribute("value", message)
```

and

```
  For Each element As HtmlElement In browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")


        If element.GetAttribute("type") = "submit" Then

            element.InvokeMember("click")

        End If
    Next
```

but my problem is that after around the fifth time the loop is run it srrors on the line with the set attribute.  And i have a feeling that it is not waiting for the webpage to load before it tries filling out the form, and that is why it is erroring.

Does anyone know a better way to do this?

Comment: System.NullReferenceException was unhandled

Comment: Can't you use `DocumentComplete` Event?

Answer (score 1):

You can use DocumentCompleted Event, this event ensures your document is ready, and all required sections loaded

```
Private Sub browser_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles browser.DocumentCompleted
    ' YOUR FORM FILLING CODE HERE


End Sub
```

and for form submit you can use, forms' submit() method like this

```
browser.Document.GetElementById("text").DOMElement.form.submit()
```

Comment: the only problem i can see with this is that when i click submit it loads a new page, so after it clicks submit wouldnt it just rerun what is in this sub and error because there is no form to fill in?

Comment: You can check for `browser.Document.GetElementById("text") IsNot Nothing` before setting value to it.
But I would use my fom filling code in `DocumentCompleted` event to be sure of page being fully loaded

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the element "text" isn't loaded yet or isn't on the page?

You could make some javascript to do that task, and inject it into the page.

Here is how to make a "click" in javascript:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createEvent

Comment: I know that the "text" part of the page isnt loaded and that is what is giving me the error, how could i fix this.

Comment: Instead of an infinite loop looking for a condition, it should register a load handler, in vb it looks like that is called DocumentCompleted, see the other answer above.